# how to get plural data from same table in oracle DB for various condition

Tags: oracle, toad

i want to get 4 column. these things are on the same column. but i want to get them from different condition. So i run this.

```
  SELECT cd_nm ,cd_nm , cd_nm , cd_nm FROM HAKSA.HL_NCS_C where CD_LVL=1,2,3,4;
```

Well, i know this doesn't work definitely, i know it was wrong sql statement. so i run

```
  SELECT cd_nm ,cd_nm , cd_nm , cd_nm FROM HAKSA.HL_NCS_C where CD_LVL=1;
```

definitely, i got 4 same column.
but i don't figure out how to get my goal, and i think you will knows what i want.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess from the given information what you actually want, but I guess you want to pivot the values of `cd_nm` based on `cd_lvl`, here is the code to do that..

```
SELECT min(case when CD_LVL = 1 then cd_nm else null end) as cd_nm_1,
       min(case when CD_LVL = 2 then cd_nm else null end) as cd_nm_2,
       min(case when CD_LVL = 3 then cd_nm else null end) as cd_nm_3,
       min(case when CD_LVL = 4 then cd_nm else null end) as cd_nm_4
 FROM HAKSA.HL_NCS_C 
where CD_LVL in (1,2,3,4);
```

If this is not what you are looking for, then post some sample data and the output that you want.

Comment: thanks for your advice though my pool explain. but i got just one line. what i want is list of these data that provide by CD_LVL. is there any function for this?

Comment: i remove min() than i got a data that i want. but there are so many null value. so it is hard to see. could i send that blank to bottom?

Comment: I solved. i use

select h1.cd_nm dae, h2.cd_nm jung, h3.cd_nm so, h4.cd_nm se 
from HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h1, HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h2, HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h3, HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h4 
where h1.cd_lvl=1 and h2.up_cd=h1.cd and h3.up_cd=h2.cd and h4.up_cd=h3.cd order by h1.cd,h2.cd,h3.cd;

anyway, thanks very much.